# How to get residuals from statsmodels AutoRegResults? model.resid returns all NaN

Tags: python-3.x, nan, statsmodels, autoregressive-models

I am trying to plot the residuals from statsmodels' AutoRegResults, but `results.resid` only returns `NaN` when I call the method. However, when I call `plot_diagnostics()` it is able to plot the regularized residuals with no issues. How can I get the actual residuals?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.tsa.ar_model import AutoReg
import warnings

df=pd.read_csv('Bank_of_England_Database.csv',
            sep=',',
            parse_dates=["Date"],
            dayfirst=True,
            index_col="Date")
df.rename({list(df.columns)[-1] : 'Spot Exchange Rate'},
      axis='columns',
      inplace=True)

df['RW 11'] = df.rolling(window=11, min_periods=11, center=True).mean()


xbar = df['Spot Exchange Rate'].mean()
df['demean'] = df['Spot Exchange Rate'] - xbar

fig = plt.figure()
fig.suptitle("AR(p) Residuals")

lags = [1] #, 2, 3]

for lag in lags:
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")           # Stops a FutureWarning and ValueWarning about dates
    model = AutoReg(df['demean'], lags=lag)
    results = model.fit()
    resid = results.resid    # Returns NaN
    print(resid.head())

    plt.plot(df.index[lag:], resid, label=f"lag={lag}")
    results.plot_diagnostics()
    plt.show()
```

---

```
Date
2015-05-01   NaN
2015-05-05   NaN
2015-05-06   NaN
2015-05-07   NaN
2015-05-08   NaN
dtype: float64
No handles with labels found to put in legend.
```

[My residual plot, which is just NaN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoEAg.png)

[plot_diagnostics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nvldu.png)

---

**EDIT**

Updated code showing version with the same issue:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.tsa.api import AutoReg
import statsmodels as sm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


print(f"statsmodel version: {sm.__version__}")

df=pd.read_csv('Bank_of_England_Database.csv',
            sep=',',
            parse_dates=["Date"],
            dayfirst=True,
            index_col="Date")
df.rename({list(df.columns)[-1] : 'Spot Exchange Rate'},
      axis='columns',
      inplace=True)
df['demean'] = df['Spot Exchange Rate'] - df['Spot Exchange Rate'].mean()

res = AutoReg(df['demean'], lags=2).fit()
results.plot_diagnostics()
print(f"All NaN: {np.isnan(res.resid).all()}")
plt.show()
```

Results:

```
statsmodel version: 0.12.2
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/base/tsa_model.py:581: ValueWarning: A date index has been provided, but it has no associated frequency information and so will be ignored when e.g. forecasting.
  warnings.warn('A date index has been provided, but it has no'
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/ar_model.py:248: FutureWarning: The parameter names will change after 0.12 is released. Set old_names to False to use the new names now. Set old_names to True to use the old names. 
  warnings.warn(
All NaN True
```

Comment: Does your df contain `NaN` values?

Comment: Nope, the df does not contain ```NaN``` values.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be possible to reproduce this issue using statsmodels 0.12.2.

```py
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_process import ArmaProcess
from statsmodels.tsa.api import AutoReg
import numpy as np

y = ArmaProcess.from_coeffs([1.8,-0.9]).generate_sample(250)
res = AutoReg(y,lags=2,old_names=False).fit()
print(f"All finite (no nan/inf): {np.all(np.isfinite(res.resid))}")

# Try a Series
ys = pd.Series(y, index=pd.date_range("1900-1-1",periods=250,freq="M"))
res = AutoReg(ys,lags=2,old_names=False).fit()
print(f"All finite using Series (no nan/inf): {np.all(np.isfinite(res.resid))}")

# Try a Series with no freq
idx = pd.date_range("1900-1-1",periods=750,freq="M")
uneven_idx = sorted(np.random.default_rng().choice(idx, size=250, replace=False))
ys = pd.Series(y, index=uneven_idx)
res = AutoReg(y,lags=2,old_names=False).fit()
print(f"All finite using Series w/o freq (no nan/inf): {np.all(np.isfinite(res.resid))}")
```

This produces

```
All finite (no nan/inf): True
All finite using Series (no nan/inf): True
All finite using Series w/o freq (no nan/inf): True
```

Upgrading to the latest release might be needed.

Comment: Thanks for your response, @KevinS. I am using 0.12.2. The part that is most confusing to me is that `results.plot_diagnostics()` plots the standardized residuals with no issue. Looking at the source for the method shows that it is calling `self.resid` (essentially the same call I am making) and then standardizing the result.

Comment: Can you share the data so I can try and locally reproduce?

Comment: Absolutely, here is a [google drive link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15A_lcLR_iepoPGarS4fHZRTshzXZLFY5/view?usp=sharing) to the file.

Comment: Definitely looks like a bug.  I can also reproduce using the latest master. Needs a fix in the statsmodels method `attach_rows`

Comment: See this issue: https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/7377

Comment: As a workaround you can use `res.model.endog[res._hold_back :] - res.fittedvalues` where `res` is the result of calling `fit()`.

Comment: Thank you for posting the issue and a workaround!